# Php code-injection in telegram bot

Tags: php, code-injection, telegram

So I have this line of code that I wrote for a telegram bot, and I am wondering if I could inject some code by sending a specific type of variable to the bot.

```
**$this->tgMessage = htmlspecialchars($tgInput["message"]["text"], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');**
```

When i just do:

```
**$this->tgMessage = $tgInput["message"]["text"];**
```

I can inject everything I want, but now I don't seem to be able to.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I am wondering if I could inject some code by sending a specific variable to the bot

Comment: What do you mean with "injecting some code"?

Comment: before i used htmlspecialchars i could inject "); exit(1) and the script would stop. now it keeps running and just returns the input. So I am wondering if i could send a similar command with htmlspecialchars  changing the input

Comment: _“before i used htmlspecialchars i could inject "); exit(1) and the script would stop”_ - what script? Your own? Then you must be evaluating the input _data_ as _code_ somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to get rid of the html, try [strip_tags()](http://php.net/strip_tags) instead.

You are using [htmlspecialchars()](http://php.net/htmlspecialchars), which also escapes single and double quotes, which then leads to your problem, because intead of `"); exit();` your are sending `&quot;); exit();`

If you still want to use htmlspecialchars, you have to set the "ENT_NOQUOTES" flag, which is something different to ENT_QUOTES (which you have set currently).

ENT_QUOTES will convert single quotes to `&#039;` if it is set.